# Regular expressions match longer items

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Here is a regular expression like this:(JavaScript)

`let exp = /^>=|>==|<=|<==/`

when I use the `exp` to match a string like this:

`let str = ">==abc";
str.match(exp); // >=`

How to make it match as long as possible of items while not using `/^>==?/`?  Now I have to put `>=` behind `>==` like `/>==|>=` but I want to make it location independent.

Comment: Alternations are not "location independent", the first on the left always wins. If you want to keep the alternation as it, you can try to exclude unfinished sequences of signs with a negative lookahead: `/(?:>=|>==|<=|<==)(?![<>=])/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pattern looks redundant, use the following one:

```
^(<|>)={1,}
```

https://regex101.com/r/E1yHVY/10

---

To obtain a single full match:

```
^(?:<|>)={1,}
```

Comment: I have to construct regular regression dynamically, so I can only do like that.

Comment: @laoqiren: Even if you have to build your pattern dynamically, nothing forbids to sort items by length before joining them.